# Oracle data pump export issue ORA-31655: no data or metadata objects selected for job

Tags: oracle, database-administration, tablespace, datapump

I am trying to export a tablespace from my database using epdp however I keep running into this error: ORA-31655: no data or metadata objects selected for job

```
C:\Users\Mohammed>expdp c##mohd/1234@xe directory=exp_tblsp dumpfile=tablespace.dmp logfile=logf.log tablespaces=TBS_NEW, SYSTEM;

Export: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Jul 11 09:35:44 2023
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

Warning: Oracle Data Pump operations are not typically needed when connected to the root or seed of a container database.

Starting "C##MOHD"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLESPACE_01":  c##mohd/********@xe directory=exp_tblsp dumpfile=tablespace.dmp logfile=logf.log tablespaces=TBS_NEW, SYSTEM;
ORA-31655: no data or metadata objects selected for job
Job "C##MOHD"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLESPACE_01" completed with 1 error(s) at Tue Jul 11 09:35:49 2023 elapsed 0 00:00:04
```

I have created a directory and done all the required steps beforhand to exporting a tablespace, I thought it was a privilege issue but its not since my user DBA privilege